Uncaught (in promise) Error: `headers` was called outside a request scope. next.js14
when i go to chats page The page is not responding due to this error, and when I open the console, I find the number of errors increasing non-stop, and this sentence appears to me:
Uncaught (in promise) Error: headers was called outside a request scope.
Read more: text
chats.tsx page code :
"use client";

import { auth } from "@/auth";
import { getUsersForSidebar } from "@/lib/data";
import Chat from "./chat";
import { useState } from "react";
import { IChatDocument } from "@/models/chatModel";

const Chats = async () => {
  const [selectedChat, setSelectedChat] = useState<IChatDocument | null>(null);
  const session = await auth();
  const chats = session?.user ? await getUsersForSidebar(session.user._id) : [];

  const handleSelectedChat = (chat: IChatDocument) => setSelectedChat(chat);

  return (
    <nav>
      <ul>
        {chats.map((chat) => (
          <Chat
            key={chat._id}
            chat={chat}
            handleSelectedChat={handleSelectedChat}
            selectedChat={selectedChat}
          />
        ))}
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default Chats;

The application is supposed to show the users I have chatted with, and when I click on a user, it takes me to the chat page with him, but the application does not respond as soon as I reach the page where the chat list appears.
auth.ts that i using it in chats.tsx
export const { handlers, signIn, signOut, auth } = NextAuth({
  providers: [
    GitHub({
      clientId: process.env....etc,
      clientSecret: process.env....etc,
    }),
  ],
  secret: process.env....etc,

  callbacks: {
    async session({ session }) {
      try {
        await connectToMongoDB();
        if (session.user) {
          const user = await User.findOne({ email: session.user.email });
          if (user) {
            session.user._id = user._id;
            return session;
          } else {
            throw new Error("error");
          }
        } else {
          throw new Error("Invalid Session!");
        }
      } catch (error) {
        throw new Error("Invalid session");
      }
    },
    async signIn({ account, profile }) {
      if (account?.provider === "github") {
        await connectToMongoDB();

        try {
          const user = await User.findOne({ email: profile?.email });

          if (!user) {
            const newUser = await User.create({
              username: profile?.login,
              email: profile?.email,
              avatar: profile?.avatar_url,
            });

            await newUser.save();
          }
          return true; // indicate successful sign-in
        } catch (error) {
          catcing error...
          return false;
        }
      }

      return false;
    },
  },
});

any help i'll be thankful
